# Unpacking JSON Into Flat Format

Tags: json, postgresql

I have JSON that resembles the following:

```
{
    "ANNOTATIONS": [
    {
    "Label": "CommingledProduct",
    "Text": "NBP"
    },
    {
    "Label": "CommingledVenue",
    "Text": "OTC"
    }
    ]
}
```

I need to unpack this into a flat table with columns matching the annotation labels.  So columns based on the above json become:

- comingled_product
- comingled_venue

The JSON is coming from a json field in a source table and being unpacked into another table.

I know that I could code as follows:

```
INSERT INTO my_target_table (comingled_product, comingled_venue)
SELECT
  payload->'ANNOTATIONS'->0->>'Text',
  payload->'ANNOTATIONS'->1->>'Text'
FROM my_source_table;
```

However, I would rather not use the ordinals of the annotations. I would prefer to use some syntax mirroring the psuedo-code below:

```
INSERT INTO my_target_table (comingled_product, comingled_venue)
SELECT
  payload->'ANNOTATIONS'->'label="ComingledProduct"'->>'Text',
  payload->'ANNOTATIONS'->'label="ComingledVenueID"'->>'Text'
FROM my_source_table;
```

Can anyone tell me if what I'm trying to ahcieve is possible and how to do it?  There are more than the two annotations I have included in the sample, so anything that involves multiple joins is probably a no go.

Using PostGres 10.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=4d19d8d3ee0594e7f19f3ce995b2544a)

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 
        elems.value
    FROM 
        my_source_table,
        json_array_elements(payload -> 'ANNOTATIONS') elems
)
SELECT 
    (SELECT value ->> 'Text' FROM cte WHERE value ->> 'Label' = 'CommingledProduct'),
    (SELECT value ->> 'Text' FROM cte WHERE value ->> 'Label' = 'CommingledVenue')
```

1. Expanding the array into one row per array element and store this result for further usage into a CTE
2. This result can be used to query the expected values (without doing the expanding twice)

---

Could be a little bit faster:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=e1a883ecc2625bcdc041485efcc51f81)

```
SELECT
    payload,
    MIN(the_text) FILTER (WHERE label = 'CommingledProduct'),
    MIN(the_text) FILTER (WHERE label = 'CommingledVenue')
FROM (
    SELECT 
        payload::text AS payload,
        elems ->> 'Label' AS label,
        elems ->> 'Text' AS the_text
    FROM 
        my_source_table,
        json_array_elements(payload -> 'ANNOTATIONS') elems
) s
GROUP BY payload
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer from @S-Man is great and you should use that for your postgres 10.7.  json_path will be added in postgres 12, which will allow you to do something a little bit closer to your pseudo-code, but only with jsonb (not json):

```
INSERT INTO my_target_table (comingled_product, comingled_venue)
SELECT jsonb_path_query(payload, 
          '$.ANNOTATIONS[*] ? (@.Label == "CommingledProduct")')->>'Text', 
       jsonb_path_query(payload, 
          '$.ANNOTATIONS[*] ? (@.Label == "CommingledVenue")')->>'Text' 
FROM my_source_table;
```

The jsonb_path_query syntax takes a bit to figure out, but it is basically returning elements of the ANNOTATIONS array for which the Label equals either CommingledProduct or CommingledVenue.  jsonb_path_query returns a jsonb object, so we can use the ->> operator to grab the value of 'Text' from the object.

Comment: Great addition! Thank you for mentioning the new feature